# Why parsing string of path name is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code:

```
List<string> dirParts = new List<string>();
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dirName.Length; i++)
{
    index = dirName.IndexOf("/");
    string dironly = dirName.Substring(index, dirName.Length - index);
    dirParts.Add(dironly);
}
```

`dirName` for example contains `d/1/2/3/4/5`

So I need that in the List `dirParts` in the end I will have in index 0 `d`, in index 1 `d/1`, in index 2 `d/1/2`, in index 3 `d/1/2/3`, in index 4 `d/1/2/3/4`, in index `5 d/1/2/3/4/5`

So when I look on the List it should look like this:

```
d
d/1
d/1/2
d/1/2/3
d/1/2/3/4
d/1/2/3/4/5
```

Comment: I don't see a question. What's your question?

Comment: .NET contains a helper class for doing this kind of work called [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I would suggest using that rather than trying to parse through the path yourself.

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear enough, to get 4 close votes for being unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible implementation:

```
  List<string> dirParts = new List<string>();

  int index = -1;

  while (true) {
    index = dirName.IndexOf("/", index + 1);

    if (index < 0) {
      dirParts.Add(dirName);

      break;
    }
    else
      dirParts.Add(dirName.Substring(0, index));
  }
```

Comment: @Blam no it doesn't because of the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that this kind of path manipulation is best left to the library, lest your code breaks on strange exceptional directory names, your code works as it does because you look everytime for the same "/".

You should search after the last one:

```
index = dirName.IndexOf("/", index+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a directory, I like to use `Path` library personally. The only issue would be the use of `/` over `\` in directory name, so you'd have to call `.Replace` before inserting:

```
var orig = "d/1/2/3/4/5"; // Original string
List<String> dirParts = new List<String>(new[]{ orig }); // start out with list of original

// Get the directory below this one. (drop off last folder)
String part = Path.GetDirectoryName(orig);
while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(part))
{
    // add it to the first entry in the list
    dirParts.Insert(0, part.Replace('\\','/'));
    // get the next parent folder.
    part = Path.GetDirectoryName(part);
}

/* dirParts = [ "d", "d/1", "d/1/2", ... ] */
```

However, if you're just looking for the down and dirty LINQ approach:

```
var orig = "d/1/2/3/4/5";
String[] parts = orig.Split('/');
var dirParts = Enumerable.Range(1, parts.Length)
  .Select (e => String.Join("/", parts.Take(e)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it that way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dirName.Length; i++) {
    index = dirName.IndexOf("/", index);

    if (index == -1)
        i = index = dirName.Length; //last one

    dirParts.Add(dirName.Substring(0, index++));
}
```